# Inno Setup - How do I delete a folder within which my program is located? (Must be empty)

Tags: inno-setup

I always install my programs inside a subfolder of the C:\Soft . If I want to uninstall a program (Soft1) located inside a subfolder of the C:\Soft\, how to uninstall my program and delete C:\Soft whenever it is empty? (no other folders or files present in C:\Soft)

I am using this code to uninstall my program (Soft1):

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: {app};
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: OK, so use `C:\Soft` instead of `{app}` in `[UninstallDelete]` entry.

Comment: And your question should mention that your program installs to **subfolder** of `C:\Soft`. You never mentioned that.

Comment: No you didn't mentioned that. There's not a single mention of any subfolder of `C:\Soft` in your post. No matter how your English is bad.

Comment: And I've answered your already in my first comment. Did you try it?

Comment: My answer answers your question. If you edit your question to say that you install the application to a **subfolder** of the `C:\Soft`, I'm happy to edit my answer.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent folder of the installation is indeed fixed (you do not give user a chance to change it), just add a [`dirifempty`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstalldeletesection&anchor=dirifempty) entry to the `[UninstallDelete]` section for the `C:\Soft`:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: dirifempty; Name: "C:\Soft"
```